# Cannot Scan from Gscan2PDF on 13.10 or OCR with Tesseract

Tags: 13.10, ocr

I am having a little bit of trouble with one of my favourite pieces of open source software. I had installed Gscan2PDF (1.0.4) from the Software Centre on my 13.10 64bit machine (clean install from 13.04 & Back ups from Deja Dup). However, Gscan2PDF will not scan, I have to scan using simple scan then open the PDF to OCR it with Gscan2PDF. That is not ideal but not a deal breaker, the main issue for me is that when I select to OCR, Tesseract is not an option. I have made sure Tesseract-English is installed, but only GOCR & Cuneiform are the only options.

Please can anyone help me to get Gscan2PDF to working like it should?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved both problems by installing Gscan2PDF 1.2.0.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jeffreyratcliffe/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gscan2pdf
```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/install-gscan2pdf-1-2-0-in-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-04-linux-mint/